# How to set the classpath in java in ubuntu and how to work with jar?

Tags: java, ubuntu, jar, classpath

I'm trying to import the class from jar files. I want to place all of the jar files in the directory:

```
/home/somebody/lib/java/
```

Compiling with the command given below says:

> package com.a.A does not exits**.
>       java C.java

I set the following in profile.

```
CLASSPATH=/home/somebody/lib/java
```

then exported it. Added to `PATH` as well

### C.java

```
import com.a.A;
import com.a.AA;
import com.b.B;
import com.b.BB;

class B {
    public static void main() {
        new A();
        new AA();
        new B();
        new BB();
    }
}
```

the classfiles are in the following jar_file
**a.jar** and **b.jar**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add your *jar files* to your `CLASSPATH` instead:

```
export CLASSPATH=/home/somebody/lib/java/a.jar:/home/somebody/lib/java/b.jar
```

The classpath supports directories (with `*.class` files) *or* individual jar files. You can also add *wildcards* (or use `java -classpath` option) but I will leave that off for now to don't further complicate things ;)

By the way, you don't need to change your `PATH` environment variable at all. The `CLASSPATH` is more than enough.

Comment: thank you @Paulo... is there any other method such that it would be more convenient if suppose we have to add files from more than one jar files say like three  or four jar files,  in case...

Comment: Try this `'/home/somebody/lib/java/*.jar'` instead. The tricky part is being sure that your shell won't expand wildcards for you. Anyway, I think my suggestion should work fine ;)

Comment: It's usually not a good idea to use the `CLASSPATH` environment variable because that affects every single Java program. Usually you want different classpaths for different programs, so you wouldn't want to do that.

Comment: @LewBloch But adding all the jar files that you need with all the long paths and stuff to the `-cp` option seems very tiring and cumbersome. Are you aware of a more compact alternative?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html):

It's better to use the classpath option (`-classpath` or `-cp`) to a command than the global `CLASSPATH` environment variable.